# how to store images into file_managed table from android to drupal

Tags: media

I have tried calling Drupal file service from android and it is storing images in `application/octet` format and not in `image/jpeg` format in `file_managed` table.

```
$data['file'] ='encodedimage';
$fid = file_save_data($data);
```

So I thought I will call `file_save_data($data)` to store images where I pass the image as encoded string. But it is still storing in application/octet format and not in image/jpeg.

Can somebody help me to store as image/jpeg format into file_managed table?

Answer (score 0):

The [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) module provide an easy to use web services enpoint to create file which do all the heavy PHP work for you.

In [`file_save_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7), the mime type of the file is derived automatically, likely from its filename. You can set the filename of the saved file by using the `$destination` argument.

Comment: problem in using services module is in filemime type it is storing as application/octet so i wanted it to be image/jpeg